# Set the text color of Combobox embedded in datagridview cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have a grid with few columns to it. I have mentioned a condition as if Cell value of column Amount < 0 then change the text colour of a that row to Gray. Now one of my column has "DataGridViewComboBox" embedded to it. Now when the <0 condition met,  text of all other columns from that row turns gray except this "DataGridViewComboBox" Column.

I would like to know how can I set the Combobox's selected text's colour to Gray?

```
Private Function GetComboBoxColumn_Category() As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim ColCombo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Try
        Using Connection = GetConnection()
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT hKey 'iCategory', sCategory FROM tbl_CategoryList WHERE IsObsolete = 0", Connection)
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        ColCombo.DataPropertyName = "iCategory"
        ColCombo.HeaderText = "Category"
        ColCombo.Name = "iCategory"
        ColCombo.DataSource = dt
        ColCombo.ValueMember = "iCategory"
        ColCombo.DisplayMember = "sCategory"
        ColCombo.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
    Catch ex As Exception
        ImpensaAlert(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try

    Return ColCombo
End Function '1

Private Sub PopulateExpenditureDetailGrid()
    Dim TextBoxCell As DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    Dim dc_Category As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim dc_DelChk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

    Try
        DataGridExpDet.DataSource = Nothing
        'DataGridExpDet.Columns.Clear()

        Label15.Text = "Getting Detail Records..."
        Application.DoEvents()

        StrClosedYrs = BuildOpenOrClosedYrsStr(1) 'List Of Closed Years
        dc_Category = GetComboBoxColumn_Category()
        DataGridExpDet.Columns.Add(dc_Category)


Private Sub DataGridExpDet_CellLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridExpDet.CellLeave


    If DataGridExpDet.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = DataGridExpDet.Columns("Amount").Index And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataGridExpDet(DataGridExpDet.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, DataGridExpDet.CurrentCell.RowIndex).EditedFormattedValue) Then
        If DataGridExpDet(DataGridExpDet.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, DataGridExpDet.CurrentCell.RowIndex).EditedFormattedValue < 0 Then
            DataGridExpDet.Rows(DataGridExpDet.CurrentCell.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to change the color of the text you change the .forecolor

```
ComboBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray
```

will change the color of all the text located in a combobox.

However, I dont think that datagridview combo boxes have this option by default.

Whenever I do custom work like this, I usually use [RadComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultvb.aspx). They have tons of customization options that will allow you to accomplish whatever you need.

**edit**

Ah hah, found it! - Here you [go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Apparently you do edit it just like a normal combobox.

Comment: @Nefarri:Now with the application fully developed it would not be choice to turn to any third party controls. I think I can get to the forecolor property of combobox once I can get the control embedded in the DGV cell. Just don't know how to get the control embedded in the DGV cell.

Somthing like DatagridView1.("Category", RowIndex).control.forecolor = gray should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. One is easy and the other is involved.

1. Give the column a `Flat` style. This will change the way the `ComboBox` looks. But if you're OK with that, then this is the easy approach. Simply add the following line to your `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` creation:

   ```
   ColCombo.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
   ```
2. Manually draw the `ComboBox` text in the correct color. To do so, in addition to your code, handle the `DataGridView.CellPainting` and `DataGridView.EditingControlShowing` events. This method is longer, but if you want to keep the look of the `ComboBox` then this option should work nicely.

   ```
   ' If the cell is a ComboBox cell: Grab the row ForeColor,
   ' Paint the cell as usual minus the text, then manually
   ' Paint the text in the correct color.
   ' This displays the cell text in the correct color when the cell is not in edit mode.
   Private Sub DataGridExpDet_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridExpDet.CellPainting
       If e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
           If TypeOf DataGridExpDet.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewComboBoxCell Then
               Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DataGridExpDet.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
               Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridExpDet.Rows(e.RowIndex)
               Dim color As Color = If(row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor.Name = "0", color.Black, row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor)

               Using brush = New SolidBrush(color)
                   Using format = New StringFormat()
                       e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background)
                       e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
                       e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground)
                       e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon)
                       e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus)
                       e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground)

                       'Don't do the following one - that's what we're overriding.
                       'e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground)

                       format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

                       e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue, e.CellStyle.Font, brush, e.CellBounds, format)
                       e.Handled = True
                   End Using
               End Using
           End If
       End If
   End Sub

   ' Handle the ComboBox control's DrawItem event when showing.
   ' This draws the selected item and item options' texts in the correct color when in edit mode.
   Private Sub DataGridExpDet_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridExpDet.EditingControlShowing
       If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
           Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
           cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed

           RemoveHandler cb.DrawItem, AddressOf GridComboBox_DrawItem
           AddHandler cb.DrawItem, AddressOf GridComboBox_DrawItem
       End If
   End Sub

   ' Draw the background and focus as normal, then manually
   ' draw the text values from the indexed datasource row of the
   ' corresponding DisplayValue column.
   Private Sub GridComboBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs)
       e.DrawBackground()
       e.DrawFocusRectangle()

       Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
       Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(cb.DataSource, DataTable)

       Using brush = New SolidBrush(cb.ForeColor)
           e.Graphics.DrawString(dt.Rows(e.Index).Item("sCategory"), e.Font, brush, e.Bounds)
       End Using
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try the solution.