# Style.ForeColor is not working properly on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, forms, colors

My code is:

```
grdListofItems.Rows[intRow].Cells[columnName].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

It works fine in *Windows Classic Mode* and the `DropDownList` font is in green.
But when it runs in *Windows 7*, the font color is back to black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enable `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`.
By the way, you mean a `ComboBox` or a `DataGridView` ?

Edit: This Link leads to the answer.
[Change the back color of the cell for DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920794/change-the-back-color-of-the-cell-for-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn)

Comment: If it's a ComboBox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667532/colour-individual-items-in-a-winforms-combobox
If it's a DataGridView: I tried it and it works...

Comment: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Comment: In this case, this thread will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920794/change-the-back-color-of-the-cell-for-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Comment: btw just to clarify, the flatstyle causes the dropdownlist to be "flat". Is there anyway to have the default dropdownlist with green font?

Comment: Sdid the answer help or a comment? Please, the both of you should clarify this and, if necessary, expand the answer!